# Connect two different servers while using VPN

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, putty

I'm trying to figure out how to connect two different servers which are also different sites while I'm using VPN. I can't really indicate any solid terms because I don't really have experience on this matter.

OK so let's break it down. First, I have my computer which connects to a VPN. Inside of that, I can connect to my **office servers** using **Putty**. I can also connect to any **client servers** (**client** as in someone buying our product) from this VPN too. Second, I'm going to copy file/s(100GB or more) from my **office server** going to **client server**.

The part which I want to solve is this:

I'm copying the files first from **office server** to local in that VPN then copy again the file to **client server**.
What I want to do is using **Putty** in VPN from **office server** then using **scp** to copy it in **client server**.

---

### What I tried so far

I tried to follow tutorials like [this](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/site-to-site-routing-explained-in-detail/) and also [this](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/connect-two-servers-different-ip-addresses-49247.html) but it seems that I can't really follow.
I tried to `route add` but error says `dev: bad value` and `gateway: bad value`. Can you also explain these errors?

### scp

```
scp /pathtofile/filename.any clientserver:/destination/filename.any
```

### ping and telnet

Error: Connection timed out.

If this is really going to be hard for a beginner, please let me know and please add more references that are easier for a starter like me.

Comment: One reason this occurs is that secure VPN applications only allow one occurrence so then you cannot connect to another site. You might consider a site to site connection for the main site and then the application will work on the second site. Copy files down locally to transfer data between sites

Comment: Yes @John, that is my current situation. You mean that there is no way to scp files from server to server from VPN?

Comment: You can move files from one server to your local machine and then connect to the other and move back. Otherwise you need to connect the site together with a site to site connection. That is not always feasible.

Comment: If somehow we connected them, is the transfer rate goes up? Because copying from server to local and to another server is time consuming whereas using scp will reduce the step.

Comment: The transfer rate will not change appreciably if the Internet speed is the same

Answer (score 1):

A VPN creates a virtual point-to-point connection between the client and the VPN
server. It is unsuited for directly connecting two computers without passing
through the VPN server.
To have this functionality, you need a product that creates a virtual network
where the participants are visible to each other, without the need to pass
through a central server.

One suitable product I know of is
[Hamachi by LogMeIn](https://www.vpn.net/).
I have used Hamachi when it was free (before it was bought by LogMeIn),
and it was an excellent product. However, LogMeIn has made it into a costly
commercial product.

Otherwise, you could use a screen-sharing product based on
[VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)
for establishing a point-to-point connection between the two computers.

An example here is
[TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/),
free for personal use. The TeamViewer server is only used to establish
the connection between the two participants, and all following file transfers
or screen-sharing is done via direct connection between the two computers.